# Python transparent watermark is not transparent

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, transparent, watermark

I have this issue, where whatever watermark I put, the background, which is transparent, appears as non-transparent.

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob


def watermark_with_transparency(input_image_path, output_image_path, watermark_image_path):
    base_image = Image.open(input_image_path)  # open base image
    watermark = Image.open(watermark_image_path)  # open water mark
    width, height = base_image.size  # getting size of image
    width_of_watermark, height_of_watermark = watermark.size
    position = [width / 2 - width_of_watermark / 2, height / 2 - height_of_watermark / 2]
    position[0] = int(position[0])
    position[1] = int(position[1])
    water = watermark.copy()
    water.convert('RGBA')
    water.putalpha(70)

    water.save('solid.png')

    transparent = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    transparent.paste(base_image, (0, 0))
    transparent.paste(water, position, mask=water)
    transparent.show()
    transparent.convert('RGB').save(output_image_path)
    print('Image Done..!')


for inputImage in glob.glob('images/*.jpg'):
    output = inputImage.replace('images\\', '')
    outputImage = 'watermark images\\' + str(output)

    watermark_with_transparency(inputImage, outputImage, 'watermark images/watermark.png')
```

Here you may see what the result is:
[image]

Comment: hard to tell without the transparent pictur at hand. It looks as if your waterimage is not cropped to the things you want to show but has (black) background of its own which then is made 70% translucent and pasted on top. You need to use a mask image on the waterimage and set all pixels to 0 transparency that are background -save it and use that as waterthingy

Comment: Kindly show your input image, your waterthingy (!) image and, if possible, the expected result.